# How to correctly set background image to div in Chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, frontend

I am learning frontend development and the task is to make diagonal div with image inside. I did it, and in Firefox it looks great, but when I opens it in Chrome it displays incorrectly.

What could be the reason? How I can fix it in Chrome?

Fiefox:

[image]

Chrome:

[image]

So far I did it in this way:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  height: 300px;
}

.red-div {
  background-color: red;
  width: calc(50% - 50px);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.orange-div {
  width: calc(50% + 50px);
  height: 100%;
  background: orange;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-left: 100px solid red;
  border-bottom: 327px solid transparent;
  background: url("https://picsum.photos/id/1/800/800");
  background-size: 527px;
  background-position: -200px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="red-div">Test</div>
  <div class="orange-div"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: could be more simple in SVG

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}
.image-div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #f00;
  background-image: url(https://www.talkwalker.com/images/2020/blog-headers/image-analysis.png);
  background-size: 60% 100%;
  background-position: right center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.image-div::before {
  content: " ";
  -ms-transform: rotate(20deg);
  transform: rotate(20deg);
  position: absolute;
  height: 150%;
  width: 20%;
  background: #f00;
  top: -100px;
  left: 28%;
}
```

```html
      <div class="container">
        <div class="image-div">

        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your response. It is fixed that strange problem with chrome, but now it is not responsive. When you change screen size the bottom goes to the top.